# Generate cartesian product of lists in order of decreasing product of entries (entries are positive numbers, lists are sorted)

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration, cartesian-product

Suppose I have several sorted lists of positive numbers, like so for example:

```java
double[] a1 = new double[]{0.70, 0.20, 0.10};
double[] a2 = new double[]{0.80, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05};
double[] a3 = new double[]{0.60, 0.15, 0.14, 0.10, 0.01};
```

I want to iterate through the Cartesian product of these arrays in the order of decreasing product of entries, like so:

```
0000: Combo[product=3.36e-01, vals=[0.70, 0.80, 0.60], indexes=[0, 0, 0]]
0001: Combo[product=9.60e-02, vals=[0.20, 0.80, 0.60], indexes=[1, 0, 0]]
0002: Combo[product=8.40e-02, vals=[0.70, 0.80, 0.15], indexes=[0, 0, 1]]
0003: Combo[product=7.84e-02, vals=[0.70, 0.80, 0.14], indexes=[0, 0, 2]]
0004: Combo[product=5.60e-02, vals=[0.70, 0.80, 0.10], indexes=[0, 0, 3]]
0005: Combo[product=4.80e-02, vals=[0.10, 0.80, 0.60], indexes=[2, 0, 0]]
...
```

In the example above, the first entry is obvious (as arrays are sorted) and it is a combination of the first values: `[0.70, 0.80, 0.60]` with product `0.70*0.80*0.60 = 3.36e-01` and corresponding value indexes in arrays `a1, a2, a3` are `[0, 0, 0]`. Now the second entry is less obvious, should we change `0.70` to `0.20`? Or `0.60` to `0.15`? Or `0.80` to `0.10`? The second should be `[0.20, 0.80, 0.60]`with product `9.60e-02`, indexes `[1, 0, 0]`.

Here is a program in Java to generate/print them: https://repl.it/repls/FilthyGreatRotation (all the logic is in `printWholeCartesianProduct()` method)
This program generates them in lexicographic order and then sorts the whole set by product.

**Question**: Is there an easy way to actually generate the combos in correct order in the first place?

**The reason for this**: I don't have the lists in the first place, only iterators over some sorted collections of numbers. Possibly veeery long, length not known ahead of time, but it is known that the numbers in each iterator are sorted.

MVCE to play with (same as in https://repl.it link above):

```java
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Double>> data = createData();
        printWholeCartesianProduct(data);
    }

    public static List<List<Double>> createData() {
        double[] a1 = new double[]{0.70, 0.20, 0.10};
        double[] a2 = new double[]{0.80, 0.10, 0.05, 0.05};
        double[] a3 = new double[]{0.60, 0.15, 0.14, 0.10, 0.01};
        return createData(a1, a2, a3);
    }

    public static void  printWholeCartesianProduct(List<List<Double>> data) {
        final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        // print input data
        String matrix = data.stream()
            .map(l -> l.stream().map(df::format).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
            .map(row -> "[" + row + "]")
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        System.out.println("Input data:\n" + matrix);

        // collect combos as they are generated
        final List<Combo> combos = new ArrayList<>();
        Consumer<int[]> callback = indexes -> {
            double[] v = new double[indexes.length];
            double prod = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
                List<Double> col = data.get(i);
                int index = indexes[i];
                v[i] = col.get(index);
                prod *= v[i];
            }
            combos.add(new Combo(prod, v, indexes.clone()));
        };

        // generate combos
        int[] c = new int[data.size()];
        int ptr = c.length - 1;
        while (ptr >= 0) {
            callback.accept(c);
            c[ptr]++; // increment
            if (c[ptr] == data.get(ptr).size()) { // carry
                do {
                    ptr--;
                } while(ptr >= 0 && c[ptr] == data.get(ptr).size() - 1);
                if (ptr < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                c[ptr]++;
                // zero out
                while (++ptr <= c.length - 1) {
                    c[ptr] = 0;
                }
                ptr = c.length - 1;
            }
        }

        // cheating - sort after generation and print result
        combos.sort((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(o2.product, o1.product));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        double totalP = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < combos.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%04d: ", i)).append(combos.get(i)).append("\n");
            totalP += combos.get(i).product;
        }
        System.out.printf("Cartesian product in descending product (total p=%.3e):\n%s", totalP, sb.toString());
    }

    public static List<Double> asList(double[] a) {
        return Arrays.stream(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<List<Double>> createData(double[]... arrays) {
        final List<List<Double>> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(arrays).forEachOrdered(a -> vals.add(asList(a)));
        return vals;
    }

    static class Combo {
        final double product;
        final double[] vals;
        final int[] indexes;

        Combo(double product, double[] vals, int[] indexes) {
            this.product = product;
            this.vals = vals;
            this.indexes = indexes;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringJoiner(", ", Combo.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("product=" + String.format("%.2e", product))
                .add("vals=[" + Arrays.stream(vals).boxed().map(v -> String.format("%.2f", v)).collect(
                    Collectors.joining(", ")) + "]")
                .add("indexes=" + Arrays.toString(indexes))
                .toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the basis for choosing `[0.20, 0.80, 0.60]` for second entry?

Comment: What's the order of the result is expected? It seems  it's in descending order by product value.

Comment: I believe you need to limit your numbers to be non-negative numbers only.  If negative numbers are allowed, there is no algorithm can do it, since the product of two big (big in their absolute values) negative numbers produces a big positive number.  And you can not foresee a "Big" negative number in the very tail of the list.

Comment: @caisil that's exactly what's stated in the requirement, decreasing product value

Comment: @SomeDude This has the second largest product of all combinations. You can run the program online on http://repl.it  to see for yourself all 59 combos possible in this case

Comment: @RobinHsu Right, the numbers are all positive.

Comment: The sorted lists are more than 3? And the length of them do not equal with each other?

Comment: @caisil the number of lists should not matter to the algorithm. Length is not equal, but that also should not matter.

Comment: note that since everybody is positive, you may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417578/generate-cartesian-product-in-decreasing-sum-order

Comment: @user753642 thanks, that's a very relevant link!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Java, but since it's mainly just an algorithm, pseudo-code should be enough:

```
Input:
Non-empty lists A, B, C: containing positive number(s).

Pseudo-code:
type-define tuple3 = (iterator, iterator, iterator);
function double value(tuple3 x) {
  return x.elm[0].value() * x.elm[1].value() * x.elm[2].value();
}
function boolean greater_than (tuple3 x, tuple3 y) {
  return (value(x) > value(y));
}
function void main() {
  iterator a = A.first();
  iterator b = B.first();
  iterator c = C.first();
  set<tuple3> Visit;
  PriorityQueue<tuple3, greater_than>  Q;
  Q.add((a,b,c));
  Visit.add((a,b,c));
  while (!Q.empty()) {
     tuple x = Q.pop_top();
     output(x);
     (a, b, c) = x;
     if (a.next() != null && !Visit.contains((a.next(), b, c))) {
         Q.add((a.next(), b, c));
         Visit.add((a.next(), b, c));
     }
     if (b.next() != null && !Visit.contains((a, b.next(), c))) {
         Q.add((a, b.next(), c));
         Visit.add((a, b.next(), c));
     }
     if (c.next() != null && !Visit.contains((a, b, c.next()))) {
         Q.add((a, b, c.next()));
         Visit.add((a, b, c.next()));
     }
  }
}
```

Note that `output()` function print out an output line.  I do not really handle index printing, but that should be fairly easy, right? (For example, just keep track of indices by extend the `3-tuple` to `6-tuple`, to hold the indices by the extra 3 elements.)
It should be easy to extend this algorithm to problems with number of lists greater than 3.

**UPDATE**

In fact, we can prove that in the worst case, O(N^2) storage is needed, if we want to optimize speed.  Since O(exploration boundary) = O(N^2), our storage use is at least just some constant factor larger than the optimal solution.

Not to provide an official proof, but I want to explain it in 2D, i.e. 2 lists multiplication rather than 3.  Then, it's easy to extend the explanation.

Assume we have list A, B, with N positive numbers descending-sorted.
We have those NxN multiplication results arranged in a 2D array.  For example when N = 4, it look like:

```
o > o > o > *
v   v   v   v
o > o > * > o
v   v   v   v
o > * > o > o
v   v   v   v
* > o > o > o
```

Each `o` or `*` represents a multiplication result.  `>` means "greater than".

The top-left `o` represents `A[0] * B[0]`.  Each step to rightward means to use +1 index for `A[]`, and each step downward means to use +1 index for `B[]`.  For a same column, `A`'s index is the same.  For a same row, `B`'s index is the same.

Consider the `*`'s:  We only know `A[]` and `B[]` are descending-sorted.  But we don't know how 'descending' each step is.  Thus those `*`'s can be in any order! Any of those 4! orders.  If you don't at least save those in some pre-ordered structure (heap, priority queue, etc..), we have to read and compare it again and again (i.e. sort those 4 products), which defeat the optimize-speed assumption.

Thus we already explained, why N storage is needed.

Now we need prove our 2D version algorithm (i.e. 2 lists product) needs only at most 2N storage.

I just want to give a hint.  A complete proof would be too long.
For example, if in the middle of our algorithm, the priority queue stores the 4 `*`'s.  Assuming one of the `*` is visited, and two of them is inserted into the queue, as follows:

```
o > o > o > *
v   v   v   v
o > o > P > N
v   v   v   v
o > * > N > o
v   v   v   v
* > o > o > o
```

where `P` means the previous one, i.e. the highest value pop out of queue, and `N` means the next twos, generated by +1 to each index adjacent to `P`.   It's clear that those two `N` can not be selected as the highest value (since one of the `*` has larger product than each of them). Untill those higher ones are pop out of queue, those `N` can not generate new ones into the queue.  Now, at least two `*`'s "Progress" direction are blocked!  That means when one of the two is selected (i.e. highest value to pop-out), it can only generate one new product into the queue.  The queue is then maintained in 2N size at most.

Applying this to 3D, we know that the storage should be O(N^2).

**UPDATE**  storage usage for "set" implementation

Someone may ask, how about the "set"?  Set is normally implemented as a hash table, proportional to the number of used entries.  A naive implementation may need to store all the products (i.e. O(N^2) for 2D version, and O(N^3) for 3D version).  A careful tweak to delete entries that never been needed, would make the storage need smaller.   Consider any product in 2D version, can only be reached by at most 2 other products.  i.e. the number of tests of Set.Contains() are executed at most twice per product.  If we keep a count, and remove those unused hash entry, it will keep those "Needed" entry really very adjacent to those products inside our queue.  That means, in 2D version, the hash table also use O(N) storage, and O(N^2) for 3D version.

Comment: Looks to be the same as another answer suggested in the comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421290/88814. I was hoping for a more direct iteration without having to store the whole exploration boundary. Which might not be possible, I don't know.