# Can solutions to this problem be iterated over efficiently in sorted order?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

So, I have a problem. We have a `list` of `Element`, each with a score (that is a positive non-zero float). We want to take `n` of them and make a `Group` with the highest score. Not all `Groups` are valid though. Now, that sounds a lot like an np-hard problem, but it isn't because we know that taking an Element out of a Group and replacing it with another Element improves the Group's score if and only if the new Element has a higher score than the old Element.

Now that I've laid out the problem, you should know that I've already solved it by sorting the list of Elements by score and taking the n highest scoring Elements that make a valid Group. I then went ahead and wrote some code to list every solution to the problem in an approximate ordering from best to worst. This is slow to run, but still doable since the actual problems that I care about aren't that big, but I'd still like to know if it's possible to do it efficiently and more correctly. Here's that code:

```
def optimal_solution_iter(self, elms, size):
    ''' Iterate over all of the possible solutions from best to worst. '''
    elms = sorted(elms, key=lambda x: x.score[1], reverse=True)
    if len(elms) < size:
        raise ValueError("elms has length {}, not enough to make solutions of size {}.".format(len(elms), size))
    ora = self.oracle()
    for select in itertools.combinations(range(len(elms)), size):
        attempt = [elms[ind] for ind in select]
        grp = Group(attempt, ora)
        if grp.is_valid():
            yield grp
```

Now, to my eyes, this looks a lot like a dynamic programming problem, but I no longer have my algorithms textbook memorized and this is getting a bit far from what I'm actually paid for. What do you guys think could be done to solve this? I'm sorry for being vague about the problem, but the specifics are private and this should have the relevant details.

Edit:

A lot of people want more details about `is_valid`, so here it is. It's actually extremely simple.

```
def is_valid(self):
    ''' Check that a Group is actually valid. '''
    valid_parts = len(set(elm.part for elm in self.elms)) == len(self.elms)
    return valid_parts
```

Comment: The best optimisation is probably in taking the business rules in `is_valid` into your algorithm so that you can more quickly eliminate whole bunches of combinations which you can predict will not pass that test. As you haven't given details about `is_valid`, I cannot know whether this is possible and cannot tell you how, if it is. But for instance, it may be that if a group is invalid, any extention of that group with one more element is guaranteed to be invalid too. You can use this knowledge.

Comment: Is `size` much smaller than `len(elms)`?

Comment: If `size`  is large, and if any group having both of the 2 greatest values is considered invalid, then this could take a looooong time.

Comment: @trincot is right. This solution only works under a pretty specific set of circumstances. Calculating all combinations for a set is 2^n...

Comment: @trincot, size is usually two or three while elms is usually hundreds or thousands. As for incorporating the business logic into the iterator, that was actually a really helpful suggestion. I was thinking that is_valid wasn't that important since it's a cheap function, but if we can reduce the combinations we need to check by any amount, that's extremely valuable. I'd have to do a lot of refactoring, but that's useful anyway.

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about is_valid.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider Can you score only groups, or can you score any subset and only some subsets are groups?

Comment: @btilly, you can make a group out of any set of elements, but not necessarily a valid one. I'll add some more details on is_valid in a minute.

Comment: I'l not sure what the implementation of `is_valid` means, because it has more closing parentheses than opening ones. Can you correct?

Comment: @trincot, sorry trincot, it should be fixed now. I guess I'm not as awake as I thought.

Comment: So, I'm thinking the way to optimize this is to store this in a new data structure that makes iterating over Elements that have identical part attributes easy.

Comment: OK, so that closes your question really... Maybe do that and come back with a new question if there still is an issue to tackle.

Comment: @trincot It solves the problem of generating the valid sets, but not the problem of generating them in sorted order.  Efficiently solving that probably involves some interesting logic.

Comment: @btilly: I was thinking that if you had that data structure, you could use some kind of heap to generate them in sorted order. Work has been limiting my ability to do this, but I've done some of the prerequisite refactoring.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417578/generate-cartesian-product-in-decreasing-sum-order

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Similar, but distinct.

Comment: That should solve the case where size = #parts, then you can wrap it in a loop that chooses which size parts to enumerate from and merge the streams using heapq.merge.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider Yes, I think you'd want to used a heap for that.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html.

Comment: @btilly: I'm using a SortedSet right now, just because heapq doesn't have a convenient way to prevent duplicate elements.

Comment: I solved this problem, thanks for the help everyone. I'll see if I can type up the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you validity constraint is that parts in a group must all be distinct. So, the optimal group should be formed of the elements with the maximum score in each part.  This can be determined by first building a dictionary of maximum elements for each part identifier.  Then taking the N largest scores out of these maximum elements.

Test data (you should have provided somthing like this in your question):

```
from collections import namedtuple
ELM = namedtuple("ELM","score,part")
elm = [ELM(10,"A"),ELM(5,"A"),ELM(3,"B"),ELM(7,"C"),ELM(1,"C"),ELM(4,"D")]
```

Solution (not an iterator, it produces an optimal group directly):

```
import heapq
def optimal_solution(elm,size):
    maxElm = dict()
    for e in elm:
        if e.part not in maxElm or e.score>maxElm[e.part].score:
            maxElm[e.part] = e

    return heapq.nlargest(size,maxElm.values(),key=lambda e:e.score)

print(optimal_solution(elm,2))
        
# [ELM(score=10, part='A'), ELM(score=7, part='C')]

print(optimal_solution(elm,3))

# [ELM(score=10, part='A'), ELM(score=7, part='C'), ELM(score=4, part='D')]
```

This will produce an optimal group in roughly O(N). Complexity is actually greater than that depending on the size (G) of your groups and the number (P) of distinct parts T(N + P x logG). That additional complexity may or may not be relevant relative to N.

If you need to get all groups that produce an equivalent total score, you'll have to play with combinations that use other elements with the same value/part content (look into product() from itertools for that).

Here's what an iterator solution (yielding all optimal combinations) could look like:

```
from itertools import combinations,product
def optimal_solution_iter(elm,size=2):
    maxElm = dict()
    for e in elm:
        if e.part not in maxElm or e.score>=maxElm[e.part][0].score:
            maxElm.setdefault(e.part,[]).append(e)

    optimal  = sorted(maxElm.values(),key=lambda es:-es[0].score)
    minScore = optimal[size-1][0].score
    optimal  = [es for es in optimal if es[0].score >= minScore]

    minParts  = sum(es[0].score == minScore for es in optimal)
    topUse    = len(optimal) - minParts
    minUse    = size - topUse
    for headParts in product(*optimal[:topUse]):
        for minCombo in combinations(optimal[-minParts:],minUse):
            for tailParts in product(*minCombo):
                yield headParts+tailParts
```

output:

```
ELM = namedtuple("ELM","score,part,ID") # added "ID" to distinguish duplicates
elm = [ELM(10,"A",1),ELM(5,"A",2),ELM(3,"B",3),
       ELM(7,"C",4),ELM(1,"C",5),ELM(7,"C",6),
       ELM(4,"D",7),ELM(4,"D",8),ELM(4,"F",9),ELM(2,"F",10)]

for s in optimal_solution_iter(elm,3): print(s)

(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
```

[EDIT] getting all solutions is a simpler form of the above:

```
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import combinations,product
def all_solutions(elm,size):
    eDict = dict()
    for e in elm:
        eDict.setdefault(e.part,[]).append(e)
            
    partElements = [sorted(es,key=lambda e:-e.score) for es in eDict.values()]
    partElements.sort(key=lambda es:-es[0].score)
    
    for partCombo in combinations(partElements,size):
        for solution in product(*partCombo):
            yield solution
```

output:

```
ELM = namedtuple("ELM","score,part,ID") 
elm = [ELM(10,"A",1),ELM(5,"A",2),ELM(3,"B",3),
       ELM(7,"C",4),ELM(1,"C",5),ELM(7,"C",6),
       ELM(4,"D",7),ELM(4,"D",8),ELM(4,"F",9),ELM(2,"F",10)]

for s in all_solutions(elm,2): print(s)

(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=1, part='C', ID=5))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=1, part='C', ID=5))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10))
(ELM(score=10, part='A', ID=1), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=5, part='A', ID=2), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8))
(ELM(score=1, part='C', ID=5), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7))
(ELM(score=1, part='C', ID=5), ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10))
(ELM(score=1, part='C', ID=5), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=1, part='C', ID=5), ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=4), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=7, part='C', ID=6), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=1, part='C', ID=5), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7), ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10))
(ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8), ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9))
(ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8), ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10))
(ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=7), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=4, part='D', ID=8), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=4, part='F', ID=9), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
(ELM(score=2, part='F', ID=10), ELM(score=3, part='B', ID=3))
```

Comment: It's true that the optimal group of size-n is one with the elements with the n-highest score, but from different sets, but you've misunderstood the question. I already had code to get the optimal solution and was asking for help to get every possible solution. I made my own solution recently and would probably post a sanitized version of it here once I have some time to relax.

Comment: I did misunderstand the question.  Anyhow, I added an iterator to get all solutions for future reference. The dictionary and each of its element lists can be sorted to make the most optimal one come out first but that would not give a perfect order farther down the iterations.